# automatically create variable in python

Tags: python, dictionary, global-variables

I have to define a function which return from dictionary keys with highest values. In case of a single key with highest value it's ok but if i have more than one keys with same values how do I return them without knowing before hand how many key have same values.

for e.g in below code there are 3 keys with same values-

```
counts = {'White icicle': 64, 'Snow belle': 63, 'Cherry belle': 58, 'French breakfast': 72, 'Daikon': 63, 'Bunny tail': 72, 'Sicily giant': 57, 'Red king': 56, 'Plum purple': 56, 'April cross': 72}

def winner(counts):
    winner_name = "No winner"
    winner_votes = 0
    t = 1
    for name in counts:
        if counts[name] > winner_votes:
            winner_votes = counts[name]
            winner_name = name
    for name, votes in counts.iteritems():
        if votes == winner_votes and name != winner_name:
            t += 1
    print "There are total %d winners tied for number 1 spot" %t
    return winner_votes, winner_name
winner(counts)
```

Comment: Append to a table and get table `len`?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this relatively simply:

```
maxval = max(counts.values())
winners = [key for key, val in counts.items() if val == maxval]
```

For example:

```
maxval == 72

winners == ['Bunny tail', 'French breakfast', 'April cross']
```

You can use this as follows:

```
print "There are {0} winners tied for number 1 spot.".format(len(winners))
print "Winners are:"
for index, winner in enumerate(winners, 1):
    print "{0}. {1}".format(index, winner)
```

Which gives:

```
There are 3 winners tied for number 1 spot.
Winners are:
1. Bunny tail
2. French breakfast
3. April cross
```

Note that you might want a conditional to deal correctly with the singular forms (`"is 1 winner"`) when `len(winners) == 1`.

Comment: The filter (`if val == ...`) is executed for *each* iteration in the loop, so you are recalculating `max()` for each iteration, itself a full loop through the dictionary. At the very least, move the `max()` call *out* of the list comprehension.

Comment: Fair point, although it makes negligible difference with such a small dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

Keep a *list* of winners, and append to that list when the values are the same, wipe the list if the value is higher:

```
def winner(counts):
    winner_names = []
    winner_votes = 0
    t = 1
    for name in counts:
        if counts[name] > winner_votes:
            winner_votes = counts[name]
            winner_names = [name]
        elif counts[name] == winner_votes:
            winner_names.append(name)
    print "There are total %d winners tied for number 1 spot" % len(winner_names)
    return winner_votes, winner_names
```

Comment: I'd recommend `for name, count in counts.items()` to avoid looking up `counts[name]` when you don't need to.

Comment: @DaneWhite: I was keeping the code changes to a minimum for the OP, to make it easier to spot what changed.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is best be approached using Python's built-in `max()`, and a list comprehension iterating over `(key, value)` tuples of the original dictionary:

```
>>> maxvalue = max(d.itervalues())
>>> winners = [k for k,v in d.iteritems() if v == maxvalue]
>>> winners
['Bunny tail', 'April cross', 'French breakfast']
```

A bit more extensive, so that you can better see what happens:

```
>>> d = {'White icicle': 64, 'Snow belle': 63, 'Cherry belle': 58, 'French breakfast': 72, 'Daikon': 63, 'Bunny tail': 72, 'Sicily giant': 57, 'Red king': 56, 'Plum purple': 56, 'April cross': 72}
>>> votes = d.itervalues()
>>> maxvote = max(votes)
>>> maxvote
72
>>> winners = [name for name,votes in d.iteritems() if votes == maxvotes]
>>> winners
['Bunny tail', 'April cross', 'French breakfast']
```

Note that on Python 3, you should write `d.items()` and `d.values()` instead of using `itervalues` and `iteritems`.

You can put this into your function:

```
def winner(d):
    maxvotes = max(d.itervalues())
    winners = [name for name,votes in d.iteritems() if votes == maxvotes]

    return maxvotes, winners

winners = winner({'White icicle': 64, 'Snow belle': 63, 'Ch ......'})
print "There are total %d winners tied for number 1 spot: %s" % (len(winners), winners)
```

From the theoretical point of view, the downside of this approach is that the original data needs to be iterated over **twice** (once, for finding the maximum value, and once for extracting all names corresponding to this maximum value). Only you know if this actually matters in your use case, but I guess it does not.

Answer (score 0):

Keep two variables outside your first loop:

- One two save the max number of votes so far
- One to save the number of winners.

Once you have a name which has more votes, set the second variable to 0.

Ccode:

```
numWinners = 0
maxVotes = 0
for name in counts:
  if counts[name] > maxVotes:
    maxVotes = counts[name]
    numWinners = 1
  elif counts[name] == maxVotes:
    maxWinners += 1
```